Why is doing Monitor with a ProgressIndicator so slow?
Here's a handy "monitored map" function:
MonitoredMap[f_, args_List] := Module[{n = Length[args], i = 0}, Monitor[
  MapIndexed[(i = #2[[1]]; f[#1])&, args], 
  ProgressIndicator[i/n]]]

It works just like the normal Map (/@) but it shows a progress bar as a side effect so you can have a sense of how long it's going to take.
Question: Why is the following version so drastically worse?
MonitoredMap[f_, args_List] := Module[{i = 0}, Monitor[
  MapIndexed[(i = #2[[1]]; f[#1])&, args], 
  ProgressIndicator[i, {1, Length[args] + 1}]]]


Drum roll. It's because it's recomputing the length of args again and again as it updates the ProgressIndicator. Reasonably obvious in retrospect, I guess! The fastest version (that I know of) is like so:
MonitoredMap[f_, args_List] := Module[{max = Length[args]+1, i = 0}, Monitor[
  MapIndexed[(i = #2[[1]]; f[#1])&, args],
  ProgressIndicator[i, {1, max}]]]

